# Single process Python WSGI Server?

Tags: python, wsgi

Are there any single threaded Python WSGI servers out there?  It seems that every single one of the last generation of Python servers has an arbiter processes that exists to ensure a worker count.  For instance, when you start Gunicorn you actually start at a bare minimum 3 processes; one root process, one arbiter process, and the actual worker.

This really doesn't play nice in Kubernetes, because it generally assumes you have one process and a ThreadPool.  Having multiple processes can mess with things like OOM killer.  And having an arbiter process is redundant when you have healthchecks and multiple pods.  It can cause more problems than it solves when you have multiple things doing the same thing.

Are there any reliable single threaded Python WSGI servers around? In the past I've written hacks around Gunicorn.

If not, what should I be aware of? (i.e signals etc).

Comment: Slightly related, if you can use an ASGI server then [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) would be just what's described.